# How to disable the radio button for a fixed interval of time after clicking them

Tags: html, javascript

I want to disable all the radio buttons when one is clicked and then to enable it after a fixed interval amount of time after the radio button has been clicked.

```
    <input type="radio" value="LIKE" onclick="func(this.value)">LIKE
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="OK" onclick="func(this.value)">OK
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="DISLIKE" onclick="func(this.value)">DISLIKE
    <br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already answered in your previus post, Anyway Its Working for me, Can you try it?

```
    <script>
    function func(thisValue){
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('input[type=radio]').attr("disabled",true);
           $('input[type=radio]').removeAttr("checked");

           $('input[value='+thisValue+']').attr("disabled",false);
           $('input[value='+thisValue+']').attr("checked","checked");
           $('input[value='+thisValue+']').prop('checked', true);

        }, 100);
    }
    </script>
```

HTML

```
    <label onclick="func('LIKE')" style="position:relative"><input type="radio" value="LIKE" >LIKE</label>
    <label onclick="func('DISLIKE')" style="position:relative"><input type="radio" value="DISLIKE">DISLIKE</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="LIKE">LIKE
<br>
<input type="radio" value="OK">OK
<br>
<input type="radio" value="DISLIKE">DISLIKE
<br>
```

JS:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var len = inputs.length;

for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (var j=0; j<len; j++) {
            inputs[j].disabled = true;
        }
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            for (var j=0; j<len; j++) {
                inputs[j].disabled = false;
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ju5Lz7x4/).